# Target class [AuthController] does not exist Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I get this error after usual installation that works for me for years...
Dont really know what have changed now..
Can any one help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple... The issue is from Http\Provider\RouteServiceProvider.php.
To make it work exactly the way your installation have been working,
include the namespace variable

```
public const HOME = '/home';
......

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

........
```

Happy coding:-)

Comment: This "trick" don't work for me. The error still the same. I'm new to Laravel 8, too.